# Ubuntu installation on SSD not booting: possible issue with bootloader or partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I am trying to help a friend fix his Ubuntu installation, he has an SSD and an HD. The HD has Ubuntu on it with the boot partition installed together, in one single partition.

On the SSD there is Windows and another Ubuntu installed in two separate partition, Windows was installed first if that makes a difference.

He wants to format the HD and use only the Ubuntu on the SSD. But when he tries to boot on the Ubuntu partition of the SSD it returns a "*no such partition error*". If we boot on the HD the bootloader loads, and we're able to see both Ubuntus and Windows. We can even choose to load the Ubuntu from the SSD and it works fine.

I'm guessing something maybe wrong with the bootloader of the SSD partition, or with the partition itself. We tried reinstalling that Ubuntu and installed the boot partition under the "/" in the SSD, but the error still persists. What I'm afraid could happen is we format the HD, and then we're unable to load the Ubuntu from the SSD because no bootloader seems to run from it. Will we have to "move" the bootloader from the HD to the SSD?

Also, it may be unrelated, but the "*no such partition error*" happened with this SSD many years ago when he tried to install Lubuntu along with Windows.

Edit: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8CxRBt3Y9f/

Comment: You need to see where everything is. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: This? https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/558Pz4tPJT/

Comment: "The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist." Please copy again & confirm it works.

Comment: Welp. Made a new one: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8CxRBt3Y9f/ I could open it this time

Comment: You show three installs, two gpt drives and UEFI boot of both Ubuntu  & Windows. But you also have a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot of Ubuntu on sda as well as ESP for UEFI boot on sda. You may need to repair the UEFI boot and best to forget about BIOS boot on sda. You may have updated install on sda for BIOS boot, so UEFI boot on sda does not work. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose install on sda & sda for grub install. You should end up with two ubuntu entries in UEFI boot menu, and may want to change one or the other's description  with new entry & desc with efibootmgr.